# how to count duplicate values with joining mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query="SELECT distinct city_name,donnor.donor_id FROM city join bloodgroup ON city.city_id = bloodgroup.city_id join donnor ON bloodgroup.blood_id = donnor.blood_id";?
```

i want to count how many time city apear in integer..

Comment: ^ that... or even PHP's `count()`; same difference ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at group by and aggregation (count) within select.

It might look something like:

**(edited)**

```
select count(city_id) 
from city 
group by city_id.
```

That's of cause a minimalistic example without the joins. Also you don't need distinct when you try to count.